# Re-formatting user input with spaces

Tags: python, input

I'm using an input function where I want to convert any spaces in the input to `+`'s. So for example, if the user inputs `iphone 7 black`, I want to convert this to `iphone+7+black`.

Comment: This is not a "solve for me" website. Provide us with some code and what problem you face.

Comment: "IPhone 6 S".replace(" ", "+") - read the [documentation!](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `replace`:

```
>>> text = raw_input('Enter text: ')
Enter text: iphone 7 black
>>> text.replace(' ', '+')
'iphone+7+black'
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that worked perfectly! Sorry for asking such a dumb question - I'm just working on my first ever coding project and am not familiar with a lot of the basic functions that are out there.

Comment: Don't worry! Jut confirm and upvote the answer if it was useful!