# Formatting user Input with specific char at specific point in java

Tags: java, string, formatting, user-input

*Edit 2,"undeclared variable" The following is the example that my textbook provides. I may have used incorrect terms in saying undeclared variable.

- String fName = "Harry";
- String lName = "Morgan";
- String name = fName + lName;
- results in the string "HarryMorgan"
- What if you’d like the first and last name separated by a space? No problem:
- String name = fName + " " + lName;
- This statement concatenates three strings:
- fName, the string literal " ", and lName.
- The result is"Harry Morgan"

The citation provided is a guideline. Please check each citation for accuracy before use.

*Edit, Question is: How do I insert characters into an undeclared string?

Example:

```
Input: X839WS21R4E877
Display: X-839 WS21 R4-E87 (7)

Input: x83rws21b3e87a
Display: X-83R WS21 B3-E87 (A)
```

I am taking a 14 character input from the user. I need to format in spaces and " - " into the input. Also all of the letters need to be capitalized, although I have that already taken care of.

The following code is what I have.

```
System.out.println("Please enter your 14 character code.");
    String name = input.nextLine();

    if (name.length()>14) {//code thanks to namlik from stackoverflow 
        String cutName = name.substring(0, 14).toUpperCase();
        name = cutName;
    }

    System.out.print(name);
```

Here is another post I found I feel might work but I don't understand how to implement it into my code or if it would work. [Basic way to insert character into string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34687687/most-basic-way-to-insert-a-character-into-a-string-in-java)

The following link is to another similar question. [Python vs of Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454747/re-formatting-user-input-with-spaces)

This link is what came up when I tried to do a search however I am not using int to string so I don't believe it is relevant. [Example of search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5884353/insert-a-character-in-a-string-at-a-certain-position)

I believe my scenario would benefit others to be able to insert other types of characters into an unknown string. I realize that using / you can insert special characters. However everything I have found so far uses the assumption that you are using a declared variable.

I believe I need to insert the characters I desire spaces and " - " at set points using the .substring(x, x) method however I am unsure how to go about doing so with out messing up my limit of only 14 characters.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can we get an couple of example input and output strings to see where you want to add/remove characters?

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is your question?

Comment: What do you mean by "undeclared string"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your input output example correctly then the best way is to use regex groups and `String::replaceAll` like this :

```
String[] strings = {"X839WS21R4E877", "x83rws21b3e87a"};
for(String str : strings){
    str = str.toUpperCase();// to convert the string to UpperCase
    str = str.replaceAll("([A-Z0-9])([A-Z0-9]{3})([A-Z0-9]{4})([A-Z0-9]{2})([A-Z0-9]{3})([A-Z0-9])", 
            "$1-$2 $3 $4-$5 ($6)");

    System.out.println(str);
}
```

**Outputs**

```
X-839 WS21 R4-E87 (7)
X-83R WS21 B3-E87 (A)
```

- [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yFRlNJ/1)

---

details

```
([A-Z0-9])([A-Z0-9]{3})([A-Z0-9]{4})([A-Z0-9]{2})([A-Z0-9]{3})([A-Z0-9])
```

You have to devide your inputs to groups in the previouse regew there are 6 groups :

- `([A-Z0-9])` groupe 1 matches first letter or numbers
- `([A-Z0-9]{3})` groupe 3 matches 3 letters or numbers
- `([A-Z0-9]{4})` groupe 4 matches 4 letters or numbers
- `([A-Z0-9]{2})` groupe 2 matches 2 letters or numbers
- `([A-Z0-9]{3})` groupe 3 matches 3 letters or numbers
- `([A-Z0-9])`    groupe 6 matches last character

Comment: I don't exactly understand how all this works though I'm sure my teacher could help walk me through it. However I am getting my input via Scanner from the user. So I wont know what the input is when writing the code. Hope that clarifies for you.

Comment: @Everette you can replace `String[] strings = {"X839WS21R4E877", "x83rws21b3e87a"};` with the user's input thats all i makes this solution just to understand the global logic

Comment: @Everette in your case you can use `if (name.length() > 14) {
    String cutName = name.substring(0, 14).toUpperCase();
    name = cutName.replaceAll("([A-Z0-9])([A-Z0-9]{3})([A-Z0-9]{4})([A-Z0-9]{2})([A-Z0-9]{3})([A-Z0-9])",
            "$1-$2 $3 $4-$5 ($6)");
}` this should help you

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Thank you so much. I will definitely be talking to my teacher to get a better grasp of the regex groups. FYI the demo you included is most appreciated. I will be looking at that to get a better grasp.

Comment: just replace it with that i share, you have to make your brain work @Everette ;)